# Does Bing Maps have a 3D mode?

Tags: bing-maps

The following wikipedia page says that 3d mode in bing maps was discontinued

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_map_services

Whats the reason for that?
Is there any official announcement or page regarding this from Microsoft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was abandoned in favor of "[Bird's eye everywhere](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2010/11/02/changes-to-bird-s-eye-and-3d-maps.aspx)."

Answer (score 0):

A good review of bings capability is here:
http://www.georelated.com/2012/02/cloud-web-map-api-services-reviewed_19.html

Bing Maps 3d was finally retired in dec 2011 because users wanted more birds eye instead.